# Why this code is changing my main Form Background color after I open it?

Tags: c#

This code is changing my Main Form background color after I open it.

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsMdiContainer = true;
        NewCustomer openform1 = new NewCustomer();
        openform1.MdiParent = this;
        openform1.Show();
    }
```

Also is creating a border in the top of my borderless form.

Answer (score 1):

When you set `this.IsMdiContainer = true` WinForms is basically inserting an `MdiClient` control into the form for you, and that's what you're seeing rather than the actual form itself. By default it has a grey background and a sort of sunken-in appearance that was quite common in early Windows UI.

Changing the background is fairly trivial, as you can just set it on the `MdiClient` itself. You can find examples of that here:

[Change Background of an MDI Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087133/change-background-of-an-mdi-form)

Getting rid of the border is trickier because it's not directly exposed by the control itself, but you can find some approaches for that as well:

[How to remove 3d border (sunken) from MDIClient component in MDI parent form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752696/how-to-remove-3d-border-sunken-from-mdiclient-component-in-mdi-parent-form)